# Does Pentaho Kettle have a way to accept JMS messages?

Tags: mysql, jms, pentaho

Does Pentaho's ETL system, Kettle  (http://kettle.pentaho.org/) have a plugin to accept information from JMS messages?  I'd like to set up a job that can read messages each containing a hash, extract certain data, and stuff it into a table.

Has anyone had any experience with this?  Is this a good idea? Any pitfalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-1529 connecting to JMS services is available as part of the enterprise PDI package.  This factsheet [pdf] implies that JMS connectors are available at the lowest paid level: http://www.pentaho.com/assets/pdf/pentaho-ce-vs-ee-com.pdf

Here is documentation on the JMS connector: http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Fconcept_pdi_usr_jms_consumer.html

Answer (score 1):

In the link you refer to, right at the bottom it mentions JMS Support as an upcoming item in "Planned features": so it looks as though it is in the pipeline (3.2 or later), but not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an open source plugin for ActiveMQ Producer.

https://github.com/sushantkunal/Kettle---ActiveMQ-Producer

You can fork it out to create one plugin for consumer. Otherwise, soon, I will be posting a consumer plugin as well. I shall post here once it is ready.